# How to redirect IE6 users in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am following http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpBrowserModule tutorial.

I have the following configuration.

```
ancient_browser "MSIE 6.0";

if ($ancient_browser){
  rewrite  ^  /ie6;
}
```

the problem with this is that I get an infinity loop.

How do I make it work!? I'm surprised that even an example on an official doc. doesn't work.

**Updated:**

My current code

```
server {

        listen 83;
        server_name {my ip goes here}


        location / {

                ancient_browser "MSIE 6.0";

                if ($ancient_browser){
                        rewrite ^ /ie6 break;
                }

                proxy_pass http://localhost:34881 ;

                proxy_set_header Host $host ;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
                proxy_set_header Country $geoip_country_code;

                proxy_cache cache;
                proxy_cache_valid 200 302 1h;
                proxy_cache_valid 404     1m;
                 add_header Pragma no-cache;
                expires epoch;
                if_modified_since off;
                add_header Last-Modified "";
}
```

**Update 2:**

I came up with the following code snippet and it works.

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 6.0") {
    set $IE T;              
}

if ($uri != "/ie6/") {
    set $IE "${IE}RUE";
}

if ($IE = TRUE) {
    rewrite ^ /ie6 break;
}
```

if anyone has a better solution, please leave a comment..thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `$http_user_agent` instead:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 6.0" ) {
    rewrite ^ /ie6 break;
}
```

or take a look at [this](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,185060) topic.

Answer (score 1):

Add `break`:

```
rewrite ^ /ie6 break;
```

The intent with the example was probably that the config not be applied in the location that you were rewriting to.

Comment: // I've added break, but I still have an infinity loop..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you redirect the user to a part of the configuration that isn't handled by the same rule.

Does something like this work, perhaps?

```
location ^/ie6 {
    break;
}
```

Comment: // I want to detect browser type and then direct users to /ie6.

Comment: That's why you create a seperate block for ^/ie6, that does not have the ancient-browser detection in it :)